# Put a bullet before paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

I want put a bullet before paragraph  ?, I want to put a bullet before the paragraph starts

```
    \documentclass{report}
        \usepackage{float}
        \begin{document}
        \chapter{ } %if you want a name write it as \chapter{name}
        init

        \section{seccion}

        \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
         \caption{A figure}
        \end{figure}
        \paragraph{Parrafo} this is a paragraph 


this is not paragraph (
and should not have a bullet)
        \section{ seccion}

        \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
        \caption{A figure}
        \end{figure}

         \end{document}
```

example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly. In the text the bullets are defined with the command `\textbullet` while in mathematics mode you have to write `$\bullet$`

```
\paragraph{\textbullet Parrafo}
```

Which gives us here:

[image: bullet]

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{float}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{ } %if you want a name write it as \chapter{name}
    init

    \section{seccion}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
     \caption{A figure}
    \end{figure}
    \paragraph{\textbullet Parrafo} hola como esta todo el mundo

    \section{ seccion}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
    \caption{A figure}
    \end{figure}

     \end{document}
```

Comment: good, but how can I put other types of bullet?, 
and I want to increase the spacing between the bullet and the text

Comment: @x-rw You can space differently with `\quad`, `\qquad` or with `\hspace{5mm}` for example

Comment: i want use this \renewcommand\paragraph[1]{$\bullet$ \textbf{#1}}

Comment: @x-rw What's stopping you?

Comment: in my command how do I put this \ hspace {5 mm}?

Comment: @x-rw `\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{$\bullet$\hspace{5mm}\textbf{#1}}`

Comment: Thank you. `\paragraph{\quad \textbullet \quad .......}` gives the bullet the right horizontal spacing for me. (I think!).